# Error "No fixture, test, or step context is active." if there is a Func in the test parameters

Tags: allure

The test crashes with the error "No fixture, test, or step context is active." when I pass Func to TestCaseData:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPblI.png)

Example:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Allure.Attributes;
using NUnit.Allure.Core;

namespace /*namespace */;

[TestFixture]
[AllureNUnit]
[AllureSuite("Demo")]
public class Demo
{
    [AllureFeature("Demo test")]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases))]
    public void CheckCases(Func<int, bool> getExpectedResult, int number)
    {
        var actualResult = getExpectedResult(number);
        actualResult.Should().Be(number > 0);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(Builder.GetResult1, 1).SetName("01 Demo test"); 
            yield return new TestCaseData(Builder.GetResult2, -2).SetName("02 Demo test");
        }
    }
    
    [AllureFeature("Demo test")]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Cases2))]
    public void CheckCases(int number)
    {
        Builder.GetResult1(number).Should().Be(number > 0);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Cases2
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(1).SetName("01 Demo test"); 
            yield return new TestCaseData(2).SetName("02 Demo test");
        }
    }
}

public static class Builder
{
    [AllureStep("Get expected result")]
    public static bool GetResult1(int number)
    {
        return number > 0;
    }
    
    [AllureStep("Get expected result2")]
    public static bool GetResult2(int number)
    {
        return number < 0;
    }
}
```

Without Func, it passes without errors. Is it possible to make friends Allure with Func?

A simple example is attached in the example, in real tests the logic is much more complicated, so I need to pass Func

Answer (score 0):

You Need add a json file in the project as "specflow.json"
with content:

```js
{
  "bindingCulture": {
    "language": "en-us"
  },
  "language": {
    "feature": "en-us"
  },
  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "Allure.SpecFlowPlugin"
    }
  ]
}
```